# "error, denied access" (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have a problem with [this project](https://github.com/bilalbhutta/IOSNearbyPlaces), once I get to the controller where I should download nearby places, I get the issue: "error, denied access".
Might that be caused by my API key?

If someone can give a look or try to run with his API key and see if it receives the same error or if it works, at least I would have a starting point on what might be the cause.

Comment: Google API key takes approximately 5~10 mins before you can use it.

Comment: @Bilal the project do not work and i do not know if the cause is my API key, much more are passed then 5-10 mins

Answer (score 0):

My project is working fine.

```
static let googleMapsApiKey = "google maps key"
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

```
static let googlePlacesAPIKey = "Google Places api key"
```

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key

A pop will asked to enable your api dont forget to do it.

Comment: i followed all the steps to enable the key but i don't know why it not work i went to the API console, select the project, on the credentials get the API key, added the iOS restriction and the bundle id